# How heuristic function for A star path finding calculated?

Tags: path-finding, a-star, greedy, heuristics

I am stuck with calculating heuristic for A star for the famous Arad to Bucharest problem. I could not understand two things in the standard problem.

1. How is the distance between two nodes calculated? For eg, Arad to Timisoara is given as 118 but it is not any straight line distance and also not actual distance in km/miles (checked in google).
2. How is the straight line distance from all nodes to Bucharest calculated? For eg, Arad to Bucharest is given as 366, but it is neither Euclidean or actual straight distance in km/miles.

Every note/lecture online I find simply takes the readymade heuristic table from Norwis's "Artificial intelligence: Modern approach" and illustrate. No one talks about how they calculated these values for this famous problem in first place.

[image: Problem map]
<sub>(source: [ytimg.com](https://i.ytimg.com/vi/_CBhTubi-CU/maxresdefault.jpg))</sub>

Comment: My guess is that these are only made up numbers, not relying on real data.

Comment: What is bothering is, Norwis is introducing it for first time as an example while explaining greedy and this algorithm but never a word about how they arrived at those heuristic values. Strange no one also raised  a question on this so far. No where online  I could find that.